# glob is not picking all the files matching a pattern, is there an issue with the syntax

Tags: perl, glob

I have a directory where there are more than 10 files which start with pattern "my_Report".
While i tried using glod for this job,it just picked only a single file . Is there any problem with the syntax below

```
$g_map{"Rep"} = glob ("data_1/reports/my_Report*");
```

Alternatively , i tried using grep to find all the files and stored it in a hash

```
$g_map{"Rep"} = [grep {!/\.xh$/} <data_1/reports/my_Report*>];
```

My Requirement is to find all the files with specific pattern  from the directory  and store it in a hash with key "Rep"
How do i achieve the same with glob?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: In the upper command, there is a `/` at the beginning of the path. In the lower one, there is not.

Comment: @simbabque : Sorry that's a typo , but that isnt the issue , even without / , i get this problem, should be a problem with the way iam using  glob

Comment: I was going to say add the output of `ls`, but mob is right below in their answer.

Answer (score 3):

Your first call is in scalar context. In scalar context, `glob` returns (at most) a single result.

To retrieve all the matching files, use list context (like you do in your second call)

```
$g_map{"Rep"} = [ glob("data_1/reports/my_Report*") ]
```

or if you are expecting one result or just want the first result

```
($g_map{"Rep"}) = glob("data_1/reports/my_Report*");
```

Comment: I must have been typing out my answer as you were :) At least OP has a few different options now

Answer (score 2):

`glob` returns a list, but you're calling it in scalar context, which is why you're only getting a single result. Try this:

```
@{ $g_map{Rep} } = glob ("data_1/reports/my_Report*");
```

That'll turn `$g_map{Rep}` hash key into an array reference, and all of the files will be stored in it.

You can access it like this:

```
for (@{ $g_map{Rep} }){
    print "filename: $_\n";
}
```

Comment: Note that this isn't the ordinary case of a list in scalar context. Instead, `glob` behaves as an *iterator* in scalar context, which allows loops like `while ( my $node = glob 'pattern' ) { ... }`